# Замена элементов массива с помощью linq

Tags: c#, linq

Как с помощью linq заменить все элементы целочисленной последовательности, заданной с помощью Enumerable.Range на сумму их цифр.

```
var a = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Where(n => (n.ToString().Sum(c => c - '0')));
```

Comment: прям обязательно линком целиком и полностью?

Comment: Да, основная задача состоит в том, чтобы использовать средства linq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже написано ниже, заменить линком нельзя, можно сгенерировать новую последовательность, с помощью `Select`

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Select(x => x.ToString().Sum(c => c - '0'));
```

Answer (score 1):

LINQ не позволяет *заменять*, поскольку он вырос из функциональной парадигмы программирования. Вы можете создать новую последовательность с суммами, оставив старую последовательность нетронутой.

Ваш код делает именно это.

Comment: Хммм, вообще  стоит задача найти наименьшее число с максимальной суммой цифр.

Comment: можно придумать и решение вышестоящей задачи